# Compatibility between Foundation and WordPress Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming, zurb-foundation

I am creating a WordPress theme. I have finished the design using Zurb's Foundation as my framework. Everything was going swimmingly until I hit a snag with what I think is Javascript.

Please take a look here:

http://dev.andrewtanner.me/wordpress/

Two problems:

- The masthead image (specifically the word 'Napier') is not rendering beneath the fixed navigation top bar.
- When scaling down to smaller devices, I expect that clicking the hamburger would call the menu but this isn't happening.

You can check out the design here (just the framework, nothing else):

http://dev.napiercountryfestival.co.nz/ - No problems at all here so the JS etc is all good.

I do believe this problem resides with JS as when I use Dev Tools I am met with two errors:

- `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`
- `Uncaught ReferenceError: foundation is not defined`

I know Foundation relies upon JS for elements within the navigation bar, particularly if it is fixed like mine is.

I would like to know how to best approach this with WordPress. I have checked out the Codex and tried their solution concerning calling the JS located here but to no avail http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript

I have also tried calling WordPress' jQuery using `<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>` instead of Foundation's but no luck either - it makes no difference. Could it be than I'm not calling things in the right order in the DOM?

I do have a couple of smaller JS scripts, one for running the marquee and another for the countdown located beneath the masthead and I'm not experiencing any problems with these (unless I kill the dependency to Foundation's jQuery by messing around trying to get things working).

Any help you can offer would be much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: It isn't misleading - it is an answer that works. However, I think it works by ensuring that Foundation JS executes as a function of WordPress - ensuring compatibility with various dependencies. Ask austinthedeveloper for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing Foundation to be a function is easy. Open your app.js file and re-write it to look like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { 
  $(document).foundation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two jquery files in your `head tag`. Remove one of them it will fix your hamburger menu issue

your masthead goes below the nav bar because you have a class `fixed` which has a property of `position:fixed`.

in the other link you have provided you have a class `.f-topbar-fixed` on body tag which provides `padding-top:99px;` which pushes your page down resulting in the visibility of your masthead. Add the class as well as the styles defined it will fix the masthead